# Get value onclick chart.js

Tags: chart.js

Good morning,

with the code below, I would like to know how I can also retrieve the date value(example 202301, .......) in my alert: alert(label + ": " + value);

Now my alert gives me as a result, for example, JANUARY: 153.
I would like to have JANUARY: 153 202301 or even just 202301

```
<div class="row" id="sx"
        <?php
        $month = array(202301, 202302, 202303, 202304, 202305, 202306); 
        $nmonth = array('JANUARY', 'FEBRUARY', 'MARCH', 'APRIL', 'MAY', 'JUNE' );
        ?>
            
        <div class="chartBox1">
            <canvas id="myChart" ></canvas>
        </div>
        
        <?php
        $values = array(153, 152, 170, 40, 80, 112);
        ?>
                
                <script>
                var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
                var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: 'bar',
                    data: {
                        labels: <?php echo json_encode($nmonth); ?>,
                        datasets: [{
                                label: '# Months Values',
                                data: <?php echo json_encode($values); ?>,
                                backgroundColor: [
                                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                                ],
                                borderColor: [
                                    'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                                ],
                                borderWidth: 1
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    options: {
                        scales: {
                            yAxes: [{
                                    ticks: {
                                        beginAtZero:true
                                    }
                                }]
                        }
                    },
                    
                    onClick:function(e) {
                    /*var activePoints = myChart.getElementsAtEvent(e);
                    var selectedIndex = activePoints[0]._index; */
                    /* alert(this.data.datasets[0].data[selectedIndex]);
                    console.log(this.data.datasets[0].data[selectedIndex]);
                    */
                    }
                });

                    /* https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2292 */
                document.getElementById("myChart").onclick = function (evt) {
                    var activePoints = myChart.getElementsAtEventForMode(evt, 'point', myChart.options);
                    var firstPoint = activePoints[0];
                    var label = myChart.data.labels[firstPoint._index];
                    var value = myChart.data.datasets[firstPoint._datasetIndex].data[firstPoint._index];
                    alert(label + ": " + value);
                    getNewAlert(value);
                };
                </script>
    </div>
```

Do you have a solution to my question

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the current value from your `values` array.

**1- First get the corresponding key/index**

```
$month = array(202301, 202302, 202303, 202304, 202305, 202306); 
$values = array(153, 152, 170, 40, 80, 112);

$valueIndex =  array_search(153, $values); 
echo $valueIndex; // 0
```

**2 - Get the corresponding month of your `valueIndex`**

```
echo $month[$valueIndex]; // 202301
```